# Pulling Employees from table having two values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am beginner in database, and I am doing some self-study. can someone please tell me a SQL query to extract the data.

following is data present :

```
emplid type

1 Home 

1 Home

1 mail 

3 mail 

3 home 

2 mail
```

desired output :

```
2 mail
```

If an employee have home as type, I should not get him. I need to pull the employees who have only mail.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Use `NOT IN` clause, my answer below will work on you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the query...

```
    SELECT emplid, type FROM TableName WHERE emplid 
    NOT IN (SELECT emplid FROM TableName WHERE type = 'Home')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @user5440331 , glad that i help you. Your welcome :)